# Why do I need to call a dynamic route ":_id" and not whatever I want?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Here's a rather standard way to set a route in Iron Router:

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) }
});
```

Experimenting around a little, beginner as I am, I tried:

```
Router.route('/posts/:whatever', {
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params.whatever}) }
});
```

This works well, up to a point. True, `whatever` will scoop up whatever is after `/posts/` as its value, and the data context will indeed be the same as before... but linking to specific posts now won't work!

So,

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">{{title}}</a>
```

simply won't work doing it "my" way (linking to nothing at all).

I can't fully wrap my head around this, and I'm too much of a novice to grasp the source code for Iron Router, so my hope is that someone here can explain it in a manner that even a beginner like me can comprehend.

Preferably like something like this:

1. First `{{pathFor 'postPage'`}} looks inside the routes to find the one named `postPage`.
2. It sees that this route corresponds to `/posts/` followed by something else.
3. Looking inside the data context it finds that only one post is returned, namely the one with the same `_id` as whatever comes after `/posts/`.
4. It understands that it should link to this post, cleverly setting the url to `/posts/_id`.

This is wrong, most likely, and it doesn't explain why it would work when `whatever` is turned into `_id`. But it would help me immensely to see it parsed in a similar fashion.

**Edit: Cleaned up my question so it is easier to grasp.**

Comment: It would appear that Meteor has established a convention for the name of the `_id` property, a convention that apparently can't be overridden.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple set of circumstances that together lead to confusion:

1. The `Posts.findOne` issue is explained by the fact that the first argument can be *either* a selector or a document `_id`. So it's not really a shortcut but rather a [documented feature](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone).
2. As you found, putting `:something` in the iron:router URL causes that value to be reported as `this.params.something` inside the route function. This *also* registers `something` as an parameter to that route, which brings us to how `pathFor` works.
3. The `pathFor` helper takes two inputs: first the name of the route (in this case `'postPage'`) and second an object of parameters, which can come either from the second argument as in `{{pathFor 'postPage' params}}` or from the data context like so: `{{#with params}}{{pathFor 'postPage'}}{{/with}}`.

Now, here's why passing in a document from the database works if you call the parameter `_id` but not if you call it `whatever`: the post object that you retrieved from the database _has an `_id` field, but it doesn't have a `whatever` field. So when you pass it into `pathFor`, it only passes along the correct `_id` if the parameter to the route also happens to be called `_id`.

Let me know if that makes sense, I agree that this is somewhat confusing and that this "shortcut" hides what exactly `pathFor` and `params` actually do.

Comment: Thanks! It's a good explanation but it only helps me get there halfway, unfortunately! I cleaned up my question so please, if you want, have a look at the edits and how I'd like to have it explained. Even if you don't want to format your answer like that, maybe it could help you to see how I think about the problem.